# How to prevent apache from sending connection close header <s>on 304 answers</s>

Tags: php, apache, http, response, keep-alive

I have the following setup:

Some files are dynamically generated dependent on some (only a few) session parameters. Since they have not a great diversity, i allow caching in proxys/browsers. The files get an etag on their way, and the reaction of the whole web application at first glance seems correct: Files served in correct dependence from session situations, traffic saved.

And then this erroneous behavior:

But at closer inspection, i found that in his answer in case of a 304 for those dynamically generated files, apache wrongly sends a "Connection: close" Header instead of the normally sent "Connection: KeepAlive". What he should do is: Simply do not manipulate anything concerning "connection".

I cannot find any point where to pinpoint the cause of this behavior: Nowhere in the apache config files is anything written except one single line in one single file where it is instructed to send a keepalive - which it does - as long as it does not send a 304 response for a dynamically generated file. Nowhere in PHP do i instruct that guy to send anything other than keepalives (and the latter only to try to counter the connection:close).

The apache does not do this when it serves "normal" (non-dynamic) files (with 304 answers). So in some way i assume that maybe the PHP kernel is the one who interferes here without permission or being asked. But then, an added "Header set Connection 'Keep-Alive'" in the apache config, which i too added to counter the closing of the connection, does not work, too. Normally, when you put such a header set rule (not of "early" type) in the apache config, this rules takes action AFTER finalization of any subordered work on the requested document (thus AFTER finalization of the PHP output). But in my case, nothing happens - well: in case of a 304 response. In all other cases, everything works normal and correct.

Since there do some other files go over the line at a page request, i would appreciate to get the apache rid of those connection-closures.

Is there anybody who has an idea what to do with this behavior?

Comment: Clean up the language. There is no reason to flush your toilet here.

Answer (score 1):

P.S.: One day (and a good sleep) later, things are clearing:

The culprit in this case was a shortsightedly (on my behalf) copied example snippet, which had "HTTP/1.>>>0<<< 304" (the Null!) in it.

This protocol version number gets (correctly) post-processed by apache (after everything otherwise - including any apache modules work - got finalized), in that it decides not to send a "Connection: Keep-Alive" over the wire, since that feature didn't exist in version HTTP/1.0.

The problem in this case was to get the focus on the fact that everything inside php and apache modules worked correctly and something in the outer environment of them must have been wrong, and thereafter to shift the view to anything in the code that could possibly influence that outer environment (e.g. the protocol version).